# Is a Borg Cube larger than the Crystalline Entity?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

Both the Borg Cube (seen in "Q Who") and the Crystalline Entity (seen in "Silicon Avatar") dwarf the Enterprise-D.

Is it possible to know **which object is larger?** I haven't been able to find the dimensions of the Crystalline Entity anywhere.

Comment: Which Borg Cube are you talking about? There's a Borg Hypercube in front of which Enterprise-D looks like an ant.

Comment: The classic Borg Cube, the one seen in "Q Who?" I'm having trouble uploading images, for whatever reason.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: While that may be a *very large cube*, where do you take the statement from that it is a *hypercube* (i.e. a 4-dimensional or higher-dimensional cube)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The comic in which I encountered it said it *Hypercube*.

Comment: @o.r.mapper - The Borg "hypercube" is a form combining 8 normal sized cubes into a single larger object.

Answer (score 15):

**The Crystalline entity is very much smaller than a standard (Type-2) Borg Cube.**

The [Star Trek Encylopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) describes the Crystalline Entity as being "**hundreds** of meters across", versus the Borg Cube which is over 3 kilometres (3040m) along each side.

[image]

> **MAGNUS:** *I've got a visual.*
>   **ERIN:** *It's massive. **Twenty eight cubic kilometres**, a hundred and twenty nine thousand lifeforms on board. We're being scanned. They
>   haven't altered course.*
>   <sub><sup>[Voy : Dark Frontier](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/517.htm)</sup></sub>

This should give you a rough idea of scale:

[image]

Comment: I didn't think the Entity would be so small compared to a Borg Cube. Is there any time during the episode in which the entire thing is shown? I believe at the very end the whole Entity may have been shown, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @T-1000 - You can see it at the end of Silicon Avatar. It fills the viewscreen but that's mostly because it's practically sitting on top of them.

Comment: @T-1000: I suppose you're thinking of [this scene](http://i.imgur.com/VTC0hO4.jpg). Indeed, it would look larger there. However, I somehow suspect the [scenes showing the Enterprise and Borg cubes](http://tng.trekcore.com/bluray/images/cbs_qwhocube1_hd.jpg) do not match with the figures cited from the Voyager episode, scale-wise.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Sizes in scifi/space shows are notoriously inconsistent. The usual thing is to just blame foreshortening

Comment: Going off most depictions of Borg cubes seen in the various Star Trek works, the cube's dimensions appear to be 1 kilometer along each of its 3 axis. You say "Sizes in scifi/space shows are notoriously inconsistent", however the cubes' depictions appear to be quite consistent across the various Star Trek media.